# R data table - Expressing multiple subsetting conditions succintly

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10; p <- 6
dat <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(0,1),n*p,replace = TRUE), n, p) )
setnames(dat, letters[1:p])
```

I want to subset the data table to contain only the rows with columns `d`, `e`, `f` all greater than `0`. I can do this with the following code:

```
dat[d > 0 & e > 0 & f > 0]
```

However, when I try to express the same subsetting condition as follows, it gives me an error:

```
cols <- c("d", "e", "f")
dat[cols > 0]
```

What's the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can specify the 'cols', in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of data.table (`.SD`), check if it is greater than 0, and then with `Reduce` and `&`, we get a logical vector by checking if all the elements are greater than 0 for the corresponding row and use that to subset the rows of dataset

```
dat[dat[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `>`, 0)),.SDcols = cols]]
```